# How to set a default DateTime in field when new form is created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to C# and MVC.  I have a form with a number of fields and a created on field which I want to populate with the current date when the form is created.

I am using the Entity Framework approach rather than the code first approach. I am using Visual studio 2013 and version 5.2.3.0 of MVC.

I have tried a number of methods to get this working. e.g setting this with the `Html.Editfor` on the create page and also via validation attributes in the model itself.  Here is what I have got so far...

**Model...**
[Current Model to display validation attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zasH9.png)

**Home Controller....**
[Home Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwm7S.png)

**Create.cshtml...**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.allClientDetails.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

There seems to be many different ways to complete this task but I have not managed to get this working yet.  Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Please edit the code into the question rather than posting it as screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should provide a bit more details what exactly does not work here.

Comment: A `CreatedOn` field shoul not be editable in a view. Set its value in the POST method immediately before saving to the database (and your code needs to be in the question - not links to images of it)

Comment: Based on your question's title, to set a default datetime in a field for the user to either view or edit, I believe that @Naveen's approach would be the simplest using the get method. To update your db with the date, you would handle it in your post method as mentioned in the comments above. It would have been easier if I didn't have to open new windows to view the rest of your post also. BTW, you have squigglies in your Create method because model.allClientDetails is not part of the model you are passing to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is, just send value from controller as part of model. Let say your model name is Student and you have a property called CreatedOn so your controller code should look like

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
     var student = new Student();
     student.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;         
     return View(student);  
}
```

In your view you

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set defaults in the constructor:

```
public class Client_METADATA
{
    public Client_METADATA()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```